# DDR Mega2DNN xslt | Hardcode 'view all' link for each ul

Tags: xml, xslt, ddrmenu

I am using the Mega2DNN DDR Menu Template for a few sites now and want to add slight customization without affecting the dynamic nature of the menu. Basically I want to list all pages and their children as standard in lists and then add a hardcoded action button/link to the end of each ul which redirects to the parent page of the ul. Also, if possible to have an overall call to action linking to the parent page of the whole mega menu item as per the following basic mockup:

[image]

Below is my code template and without trying to going about it in a very hacky way is ther a simpler solution to my question?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:param name="ControlID" />
  <xsl:param name="Options" />
  <xsl:param name="subMenuColumns">1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="subpointer"><![CDATA[]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="pointer"><![CDATA[]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="startUl"><![CDATA[<ul>]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="endUl"><![CDATA[</ul>]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <ul class="megamenu" id="megamenu">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:param name="level" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$level=0">
        <li>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            level0 <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1">current</xsl:if>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
              level0 <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1">current</xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">return false</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
            <xsl:if test="node">
              <xsl:value-of select="$pointer" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </a>
          <xsl:if test="node">
            <div class="sub">
                <div class="container">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
                    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
                </div>
            </div>
          </xsl:if>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$level=1">
        <ul class="megamenusubcontent">
          <li class="subheader">
            <h2>
              <a>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">return false</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
              </a>
            </h2>
          </li>

          <xsl:if test="node">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
              <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:if>
        </ul>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li class="sublink">
          <a>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">return false</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
          </a>
        </li>      
        <xsl:if test="node">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated, thx

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around solution. Create the 'view all' pages and set them to hidden and then add the ​IncludeHidden="True" to the ddr menu tag ​which will only make these pages visible in the mega menu so they wont appear in the left menu of the site.